# Unable to run a Screen share chrome app using electron

Tags: javascript, webrtc, electron

I ran this [github](https://github.com/emannion/webrtc-application-screen-share) app successfully under chrome extenstion. But when I run it using electron the socket connection Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Below is package.json file.
I tried "chromium-args": "--allow-running-insecure-content --ignore-certificate-errors", but did not help.
Are there any specific changes I need to make in package.json. Just trying to learn let me know if any information is missing?

```js
{
  "name": "electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
   "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "sockets": {
     "udp": { "bind": "*", "send": "*" }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "system.network", "desktopCapture", "videoCapture", "mdns"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "pretty-bytes": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.35.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: I am sure it is not the firewall. And it is failing to get connected to ubuntu server. Is there something an electron app requires to be installed before you run chrome app running screen-share webrtc app?

Comment: Seems like you can share the complete window with the electron application, but cannot share individual application built on chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to run a Chrome App in Electron at this time, you may want to try [NW.js v0.13 Beta](http://nwjs.io/blog/v0.13.0-beta1/) instead.

Comment: Hi Vadim, I was able to run chrome app using NW.js but I am curious to know why is it not possible to run chrome app? Will appreciate links or articles because I was not able to find one.  Awaiting for the response.

Comment: @user2801184 The short answer is no one has put in the work to make it possible to run Chrome Apps in Electron yet, and I'm not sure if that's something the Electron team is [interested in supporting](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2042#issuecomment-114667969). Probably in no small part due to the fact that many `chrome.*` APIs are not available in Electron. Unfortunately I don't know of any relevant posts or articles on the subject, my answer is based on a cursory look at the Electron code.

Comment: Thank you Vandim for the comments. I was able to launch the chrome app using electron but was not able create a websocket connection. I have already commented all chrome API in the code. But still getting error due for websockets and was wondering if I missed anything in index.js file?

Comment: @user2801184 What's the error and what's throwing it?

Comment: @Vandim: It is throwing socket connection Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Now websockets is supported by Electron it should work?

Comment: @user2801184 Have you tried setting the [ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.7/docs/api/environment-variables.md#electron_enable_logging) environment variable to see if you can get any more information about the error?

Comment: @Vandim: The debugging pointed out the exact errors in main.js file. I can now get connected to server. Thank you so much for help.  I tried to capture desktop using desktopCapturer.getSources(options, callback) and getting error: Cannot read property of Get sources of undefined.

Comment: @Vandim: The debugging pointed out the exact errors in main.js file. I can now get connected to server. Thank you so much for help. I tried to capture desktop using desktopCapturer.getSources(options, callback) But I don't see the picker window.

Comment: FYI: I am getting the windows but how to create a chrome picker window?:WARNING:webrtcvoiceengine.cc(460)] Unexpected codec: ISAC/48000/1 (105)

Comment: @Vandim: Can you please answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321730/unable-to-obtain-desktop-picker-dialog-electron) question?