# Unable to obtain desktop picker dialog @electron

Tags: javascript, webrtc, electron

I am unable to get desktop picker dialog for available sources. I am newbie can someone guide me what am I missing? In chrome we use "chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia"? I obtained source from below code.

```js
function onAccessApproved(error, sources) {
if (error) throw error;
for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
{
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
audio: false,
video: {
mandatory: {
chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
chromeMediaSourceId: sources[i].id,
minWidth: 1280,
maxWidth: 1280,
minHeight: 720,
maxHeight: 720
}
}
}, gotShareStream, errorCallback);
return;

}
```

I have tried Option [link](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1380) but I am getting BrowserWindow undefined error.

Thanks!

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Have you looked at the [desktop picker sample](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/desktop-capture)?

Comment: This is what I get in debug text                                                                7 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
8 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
9 error node v0.12.2
10 error npm  v2.7.4
11 error missing script: start

Comment: The above error was for the desktop picker example.

Comment: What does NPM have to do with it? You should run `main.js` with Electron, e.g. `/path/to/electron main.js` [as mentioned in the README](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps#how-to-run-apps).

Comment: @Vandim: I am getting [this](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/issues/15) error.

Comment: @Vandim: Setting audio True. i am getting [CODE [object NavigatorUserMediaError]]. What am I missing to make it work?

Comment: You may not be able to capture both video and audio at the same time, see [existing issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/4386)

Comment: @Vandim: I can only hear my microphone audio but not the desktop audio   Is it possible to capture desktop audio only?

Comment: @Vandim: Can you guide me audio capture along with screen capture, how to create a separate stream for it and sync both@sever.

Comment: I don't know, you should probably submit a separate question about combining video and audio streams.

Comment: Thank you so much for help Vandim! I have already posted the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444604/desktop-audio-capture-not-working-for-chrome-app

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used *electron*, but in WebRTC you need to use something like this `video: {optional: [{sourceId: source.id}]}`. And don't do this for all the sources - do this only to get a stream from that source.

To get the available sources use [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) and then filter them by `kind` which can be `audioinput`, `audiooutput`, `videoinput` and `videooutput`.