# Desktop Audio Capture Not working for chrome app

Tags: javascript, screenshot, webrtc, google-chrome-app, web-audio-api

According to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223639 chromium  has issues with audio Loopback. and it never works in chrome app. Can anyone share some links and explanation to why is this not working?Or if it is possible? I tried below code but lot of disturbance in desktop audio.

```
video: {
  mandatory: {                
      chromeMediaSource:'screen',
      chromeMediaSourceId: id
  }
},
audio: {
  mandatory: {
    chromeMediaSource: 'system',
    chromeMediaSourceId: id, 
  }
}
```

Multiple streams are captured and attached to a single peer connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK only [desktopCapture API](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/blob/master/desktopCapture/background-script.js#L16-L17) are supporting **audio+tab**.

`chromeMediaSource` value must be `desktop`.

```
video: {
  mandatory: {                
      chromeMediaSource:'desktop',
      chromeMediaSourceId: 'sourceIdCapturedUsingChromeExtension'
  }
},
audio: {
  mandatory: {
    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
    chromeMediaSourceId: 'sourceIdCapturedUsingChromeExtension'
  }
}
```

Try following demo on **Chrome-Canary**:

- https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Audio+ScreenSharing.html

However make sure to enable `chrome://flags#tab-for-desktop-share` flag.

Comment: Hi Muaz, Everything works good in canary but we want something similar for chrome. Can you please help me with that? How can I capture audio for chrome? Also, it it captures microphone audio too. How can I mute Microphone audio and capture desktop audio only? Also, is there a way I can convert my chrome app to Firefox? Thank you in advance!